# "Undefined is not a function" on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, slider, nouislider

I was working on my Ruby on Railsproject and I was trying to use noUislider and I also use Big Picture html template. However I keep running into "Undefined is not a function"

[image: The error picture from chrome]

Here's my application.js file. I'm using the colorPicker example as a test right now.
I'm pretty sure I include the jQuery in the right order.

```
//= require jquery-1.10.2
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.4
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.poptrox.min
//= require skel.min
//= require init
//= require jquery.nouislider
//= require Link
//= require_tree .


// On document ready, initialize noUiSlider.


$(function(){
    $('.slider').noUiSlider({
        start: 127,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 255
        },
        serialization: {
            format: {
                decimals: 0
            }
        }
    });


    function setColor() {

        // Get the slider values,
        // stick them together.
        var color = 'rgb(' +
            $("#red").val() + ',' +
            $("#green").val() + ',' +
            $("#blue").val() +
            ')';

        // Fill the color box.
        $(".result").css({
            background: color,
            color: color
        });
    }

// Bind the color changing function
// to the slide event.
$('.slider').on('slide', setColor);
});
```

And here's the index.html.erb file

```
<div id="controller_main" class="content box style2 light_controller">
<ul class="lights_list">
  <li id="light1" class="lights">
    <span>Light 1</span></br>
    <div class="slider light_image"></div>
    <div class="slider" id="red"></div>
    <div class="slider" id="green"></div>
    <div class="slider" id="blue"></div>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I had spend more than 10 hours on this problem so someone please save me.....I need this to work ASAP.

Please let me know if there's anything else I need to provide in order to solve the question.

**EDIT:**
I delete the whole project and instead of using scaffold I just create a controller and a view called index and put the template code inside. And it works. However I still don't know why it's not working before. Also using the template is so painful because you have to integrated it into rails and some of the path is hard code inside and it is impossible to make it fully function.

Comment: It's failing in your init.js before it fails in your application.js

Comment: So maybe is because the init.js fail cause the error in application.js??

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ . Try using this

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        $('.slider').noUiSlider({
            start: 127,
            connect: "lower",
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 255
            },
            serialization: {
                format: {
                    decimals: 0
                }
            }
        });
        // the rest of your code
    });
})(jQuery);
```